# Django session authentication failed sometimes

Tags: django, session, cookies, django-rest-framework, session-cookies

I'm having very weird issue with session authentication.

I'm using session authentication over DRF APIs for some legacy django views. And login process implemented with DRF and react app.
The server code for sign-in looks like this:

```python
class AuthViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    is_session_auth = request.data.get('session_auth', False)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    token = serializer.save()

    if is_session_auth is True:
        login(request, token.user)

    return Response(dict(token=token.key))
```

So, as far as I expected, the response should has `set-cookie` header which makes browser to set `sessionid` and `csrftoken` cookies. And it works well most of times.

But rarely, *some* users experiencing login failures. I'm faild to reproduce it, but this is what they describe:

1. When user submit sign in form, the request sent to the server and got response successfully.
2. Then the javascript app push url to `login/complete`, as expected.
3. But in login complete view, the request failed to authenticate. And the view redirect request to the original login view.
4. User retry login, but got same result.

I have no idea how this happened so *rarely*, to the so *small* amount of users. Am I miss something?

Thanks for help.

==============
Add some more information.

I dig into this problem, and find out that users' sessions are not decodable.
`session.get_decoded() for session in Session.objects.all()` returns `Session data corrupted` error. Is it relevant to login failure?

Comment: Are there any error logs indicating this behaviour?

Comment: @SachinKukreja No, I can not find any error logs about this.